# Can I Teach for Free on Youtube?

Tags: teaching, audio-video-recording

I wonder if it is legal/acceptable to teach standard scientific material for free on youtube.  The concern is about copyright issues. I assume that it is okay to upload youtube videos explaining standard results in math, physics, or computer science, given that it is standard and already available on Wikipedia, for example.

One thing I also find strange is copyrighted videos for universities teaching, for example, Newton's laws in physics. Newton's laws are due to Newton, so what rights does the universities have? Is it about the syllabus, the way of teaching, or  something else?

Comment: It would be nice if the down-voter can write a comment of why the question does not show any research effort, or how it is unclear or not useful.

Comment: I guess you ask only about copyright, and not about plagiarism.

Comment: Thanks. I see now. Although I got good answers, I'm still not sure why the question is considered outside an academic setting. The question is so general so that: it is not about a specific content, and it does not refer only to non-high education.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you can do this, but you can't used copyrighted materials of others without permission (or in certain limited but permitted ways). The copyrights you see are because copyright is about specific expression of ideas, not about ideas. So, yes, you can teach anything that is common knowledge and anything that you develop yourself, and you can even copyright it.

Lots of books express the same "ideas" and can be copyrighted since it is the expression that is covered. Ideas aren't property. But the expression can be protected by various IP laws for some (hopefully) finite period of time.

Answer (score 5):

The copyright holder of standard results in math, physics, etc is *not* the author of the paper. Newton did not hold the copyright to Newton's Laws. The author holds the copyright to how they chose to present the work. The copyright holder of a lecture is the person who gave the lecture, so you cannot just record someone else's lecture and upload it without their consent. However, if you are making your own videos, then you hold the copyright, and it's legal.

Answer (score 3):

The way this is expressed by authors (at least five different ones in my personal direct experience, plus lots of them in writing) is this. The copyright is for the arrangement of words. Or the image in the case of graphics or art and such. The copyright is *NOT* for the ideas. Once the idea is out you can use it. You must not copy the words. (Or the pictures etc.)

You *MUST* put it in your own words. And make your own pictures. And, as much as possible, you should cite the source of the ideas. At least as far as where you got the ideas. If you can then cite the person who originated the idea. Some cites of people who worked with the idea would also be nice for your learning audience.

There are already several YouTube channels that do some of this. Some of them are useful and interesting. My suggestion would be to try to avoid duplicating the ones already there. Find a niche that is not already filled that you can fill. Then do a good job at explaining topics not already explained. That will get you an audience.